# Запрос добавления в базу: как получить идентификатор вставленной записи

Tags: jquery, sql

есть запрос в базу на добавления строки

```
INSERT INTO table1 (cal1, cal2) VALUES ('$val1', '$val2')
```

В этой же таблице есть поле `id`  которое заполняется автоинкриментом.

Cуть в том что следующий запрос на добавления в другую таблицу должен записать и новосозданное `id`, но отловить у меня его не получается..

ни так:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO table2 (version, id)
           VALUES ('$version1', 'SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `table1`)'";
 TestsDb::query($query);
```

ни так:

```
$idA = mysqli_insert_id();
```

В таком случае он передает 0, якобы не видит работы с аутоинкриментом.

Comment: согласно документации

> If the last query wasn't an INSERT or UPDATE statement or if the modified table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, this function will return zero.

возможно, там действительно нет автоинкремента.

SELECT MAX(id) - это плохая попытка получить id.

Comment: знаю, это было от отчаяния)

Comment: решил вопрос

INSERT INTO TABLE (cal1, cal2) VALUES ('$val1', '$val2') RETURNING *

таким подходом